# Boost singletons

Tags: c++, boost, singleton

http://torjo.com/tobias/index.html#boost_utility_singleton._usage I saw that boost has singleton class which gets second param: recreate instance if it's deleted (when we call the singleton). I can't find the implementation of this singleton in boost library. There is only singletons from serialization and pool. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a candidate library that never made it into official [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/).